# Removing empty string from consecutive delimiter for String.split?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a simple program to split a string by regex like so:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regex = "\\{|\\}|\\+";
        String input = "F-{0000}a{yy}{mm}";

        String [] splitInput = input.split(regex);


        for(int i = 0; i < splitInput.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Value: " + splitInput[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

and it prints

```
Value: 0 A-                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Value: 1 0000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Value: 2 a                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Value: 3 yy                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Value: 4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Value: 5 mm
```

I just want it so that my split string does not include `value 4` which is the empty character.  I know this is happening because the `}{` are back to back. My regex I believe just says to split on `{` or `}` and I thought the `+` will split on consecutive delmiters but that doesn't seem to be the case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Your regex is incorrect, it will split on `{`, `}` or `+`. What you want is to split on one or more of `{` or `}` which you can do with a character class:

```
String regex = "[{}]+";
```

[Demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/IPNS15932)